# How to generate a PHP soap client code?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

Is there a way to generate a PHP Soap Client from a WSDL file?

I mean something like `wsdl.exe` or `svcutil.exe` in .net, that generates code for a class that can be the client of a service, not something like:

```
$WSDL     = new SOAP_WSDL($wsdl_url); 
$client   = $WSDL->getProxy();
```

My problem is that I want the PHP client to be able the work with a service, even when that service doesn't expose its WSDL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the method [`generateProxyCode`] provided in the package SOAP_WSDL (http://pear.php.net/reference/SOAP-0.9.4/SOAP/SOAP_WSDL.html#methodgenerateProxyCode) method instead and save it to a file:

```
$WSDL     = new SOAP_WSDL($wsdl_url); 
$php      = $WSDL->generateProxyCode();
file_put_contents('wsdl_proxy.php', '<?php ' . $php . ' ?>');

require 'wsdl_proxy.php';
```

Comment: two notes about the sample code: you need to include the PEAR class with require_once("SOAP/WSDL.php"); and the method is not $WSDL->getProxyCode(); but $WSDL->generateProxyCode();

Answer (score 18):

I found generator really useful

https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator

Instructions (from github) :

- Download [wsdl2phpgenerator-2.3.0.phar](https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator/releases/download/2.3.0/wsdl2phpgenerator-2.3.0.phar) from the latest release
- Run "php wsdl2phpgenerator-2.3.0.phar -i input.wsdl -o tmp/my/directory/wsdl"

Work for web hosted wsdl too

eg

```
php wsdl2phpgenerator-2.3.0.phar -i http://someurl/input.wsdl -o tmp/my/directory/wsdl
```

Comment: Best solution ever : you don't have to use composer, it will generate a folder with all needed class and how to use them to call the remote method

Answer (score 8):

There is an app for this, it's called wsdl2phpgenerator:

http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2phpgenerator/

Run it against a WSDL file and it will generate classes based on the WSDL services.

Comment: wsdl2phpgenerator will give you a great head start

Comment: To get the latest version go to the new home of wsdl2phpgenerator, on github, https://github.com/walle/wsdl2phpgenerator

There is also a notable fork at https://github.com/reload/wsdl2phpgenerator that try to integrate pull requests I haven't really had the time to verify and merge.

Answer (score 4):

Just to help anyone else who comes across this post and thinks "how the heck do I work w/ this SOAP_WSDL thing?" (like myself)

Open the command line and get to your php directory (I installed XAMPP Lite in this example)

Once in the php directory I ran the pear.bat script.  After this I was able to type the following via cmd line

pear -V (provides the version of your install)

pear list

If you type the above and don't see SOAP you need to do the following from the cmd line:

- pear install Net_DIME-1.0.1
- pear install Mail_Mime-1.5.2
- pear install Mail-1.2.0b1
- pear install SOAP-0.12.0

Now after you install these packages and do another "pear list" you should see SOAP listed.

If so you can include a reference to the php files pulled down inside the pear directory under SOAP.

One example of this path might be C:\xampplite\php\PEAR\SOAP

Answer (score 0):

I used **wsdl2php**, a simple PEAR tool; it seems that project is dead, but you can still download the latest version here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2php/

It require a development machine with PHP 5 and PEAR, and you have to install it with this PEAR command:

```
sudo pear install wsdl2php-0.2.1-pear.tgz
```

After this, you can generate the PHP classes file with this command:

```
wsdl2php <WSDL_URL>
```

It generates a main class that extends SoapClient, and many other classed that represent requests, responses, and complex objects, so it is very useful when developing in a IDE with "intellisense" like NetBeans.

Comment: how we can install the same in windows?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to use everething that were listed here.

Found the another choise: https://github.com/mikaelcom/WsdlToPhp

Pluses in comparition with previous:

- No dependencies.    *Both for generator and created client.*
- Classes for **in** and **out** parameters.
- Examples of using for **created client**. *It's course not so important. But some times very useful*
- Less of code (In comparision with SOAP_WSDL)

Minuses:

- Answer and any complex subtype are wrapped to another object that contains technical info.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed feedback. Could you send me more details about your remark "Answer and any complex subtype are wrapped to another object that contains technical info." at contact@wsdltophp.com, it would be really appreciated, Thks

Comment: It's ,actually, not correct. In .NET you can get objects exact the same you have it at service. But In my case when I get responce in PHP from .NET Service, I've got "additional" wrappers. They actually present in WSDL, but .NET ,somehow, "knows" that some classes are just for  technical needs and remove it in result.

Comment: Thanks, if you had some examples it would be great, otherwise I'll search if it can be avoided.