# PHP class generator for web services

Tags: php, wcf, web-services, code-generation

I am trying to find some kind of php class generator for Web Services (WCF service if that matters) without any luck so far. Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Is this a SOAP service? (I don't know anything about WCF)

Comment: Yes, it's SOAP but I'm not sure if there is any difference from a simple web service. The WSDL definition seems a bit more complicated in WCF. Using it on the other hand is straight-forward : http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2007/09/17/using-wcf-services-with-php.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I just asked because when I hear "web service" I think of any API that's accessible via HTTP, whether that API uses SOAP, REST, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Question & Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656727/how-to-generate-a-php-soap-client-code), you can use the [generateProxyCode()](http://pear.php.net/reference/SOAP-0.9.4/SOAP/SOAP_WSDL.html#methodgenerateProxyCode) method of the [PEAR SOAP_WSDL class](http://pear.php.net/reference/SOAP-0.9.4/SOAP/SOAP_WSDL.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there's a dubious benefit from static generation of the classes wrapping a SOAP service in a dynamic language like PHP. What I usually do is just hand-crafting the SOAP HTTP request and then feeding the results to SimpleXMLElement, like:

```
$Response = new SimpleXMLElement($soap_response_xml);
echo strval($Response->ElementA->ElementB['AttributeC']);
```

Which corresponds to SOAP response XML:

```
<Response>
    <ElementA>
        <ElementB AttributeC="foo"/>
    </ElementA>
</Response>
```

and outputs "foo".

This way has no WSDL parsing overhead. But if you do want to deal with WSDL, and avoid hand-crafting the HTTP request, check [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.client.html) out.

In either way, it's better to "generate the classes" at runtime, because your language allows that.

Comment: Sample of hand-made SOAP request

$full_response = @http_post_data(
    'http://example.com/ws.asmx',
    $REQUEST_BODY,
    array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8',
            'SOAPAction' => 'HotelAvail',
        ),
        'timeout' => 60,
        
    ),
    $request_info
);

$response_xml = new SimpleXMLElement(strstr($full_response, '<?xml'));

Comment: I'm wondering how well this method will scale (in terms of programming effort) with non-trivial SOAP objects. I'm writing a SOAP client in PHP right now, for example, for a service that has 12 classes with several layers of nesting and multiple inter-class relationships. Does any of that complexity matter for this approach?

Comment: We work with even more complex XML of dozens of MB in size. It doesn't matter. You'd call those attributes by name against static classes anyway. AND you save _a lot_ by ignoring WSDL.