# Displaying HTCondor status using PHP

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, condor

I am currently trying to display the output of the HTCondor command "condor_q" in a browser as part of a front-end I am developing. I am working with PHP and have tried echo exec("condor_q"), echo shell_exec() and echo system() with nothing being displayed.

The front-end is running on a single machine using the web server Xampp on Ubuntu 16.04.

I would appreciate it if any has suggestion on how I can resolve this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could enable HTCondor [SOAP](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/v7.8/4_5Application_Program.html) Feature:

Add this to your config file (/etc/condor/config.d/condor_config.local )

```
ENABLE_SOAP = TRUE
ALLOW_SOAP = *
SCHEDD_ARGS = -p 8080
ENABLE_WEB_SERVER = TRUE
WEB_ROOT_DIR=/usr/share/condor/webservice/
```

Then [generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656727/how-to-generate-a-php-soap-client-code) the SOAP Php client stub ()

---

Another option is simply parser the `condor_q` command

```
% condor_q -submitter jdoe -format "%s" Owner -format " %s " Args -format "ProcId = %d\n" ProcId
```

Also be aware that the built-in SOAP API support in HTCondor is expected to go away in the v8.7 release series sometime later this year, as times and tastes have changed.